# Why i dont show positiveButton

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I made an `AlertDialog` with a "positive button" but in emulator it doesn't show up. What's the problem?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnDersEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDersEkle);
        etDers = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutDers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDers);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDers = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDers.setTitle("Ders Adi Giriniz");
        alertDers.setView(etDers);
        final AlertDialog alert = alertDers.create();

        alertDers.setPositiveButton("TAMAM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                tvDers = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                tvDers.setText(etDers.getText().toString());
                LayoutDers.addView(tvDers);

            }
        });


        btnDersEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: it might be because your are creating it before adding the button try moving  final AlertDialog alert = alertDers.create();   after setPositiveButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `setPositiveButton` before create the `AlertDialog`. Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnDersEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDersEkle);
        etDers = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutDers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDers);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDers = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDers.setTitle("Ders Adi Giriniz");
        alertDers.setView(etDers);
        alertDers.setPositiveButton("TAMAM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                tvDers = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                tvDers.setText(etDers.getText().toString());
                LayoutDers.addView(tvDers);

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = alertDers.create();

        btnDersEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify such things once the `AlertDialog` got created.

Use `setPositiveButton()` and other methods *before* `create()`:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
.setPositiveButton(/* ... */)
.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to set the negative button too.

```
alertDers.setNegativeButton("Button2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //DO TASK
}
```

and if you don't want that this button is shown, you can do this:

```
alertDers.getButton(yourButton).setEnabled(false);
```